Is it possible to construct a compact superset based on a closed continuous interval?
Let $I = [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed interval and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact. Furthermore, $g : D \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a continuous function and $f: I \times D \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is another function with $f(h,x) = h g(x)$.  In this case, we know that the image $f(h, D) = hg(D)$ is compact for some $h \in I$. Is there a way to construct a compact set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^{n  \times n}$ such that $f(h, D) \subset S$ is satisfied for all $h \in I$?

If the image $f(I,D) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is compact,then we can choose it as our $S$.
Here is why the image is compact:

$I$ is compact, $D$ is compact and therefore so is $ I \times D$.
The image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact.

It therefore remains to show that $f(h,x)$ is a continuous function:

The function $ s : I \times D  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}, (t,X) \mapsto tX$ is continuous in $t$ and in $X$ (use your favorite method to check).
The function $f_1 : (h,x) \mapsto (h,g(x)) $ is continuous (by continuity of $g$) and since composition preserves continuity, so is $f(h,x) = (h,x) \overset{f_1}{\mapsto} (h,g(x)) \overset{s}{\mapsto}{} hg(x)$.

Therefore $S:= f(I,D)$ is compact and such that $f(h,D) \subset S$ for all $h \in I$.

Thank you very much! That sounds very logical, I missed the forrest for the trees.

I figured! (That's why I used $t$ (for tree) :)
